# Facebook graph - get all user's friend's photos without going over limit

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook has a limit to allows 200 calls per user per hour (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting). When my user logs in I need them to be able to get the profile pictures of all their friends and of course many people have more than 200 Facebook friends. So if I was to make a request I could only retrieve 200 pictures of that user's friends.  I have seen apps where all my Facebook friends profile pictures show up (I have > than 200 friends on FB) so I was wondering how is this possible? How can an app get all the profile pictures of friends without going over the limit?

Comment: /me/friends only return app friends and not all friends.

Comment: yes I know this, but I am unsure how this information helps?

Comment: I would assume very few of your users have more then 200 app friends?

Comment: Generally yes, but I must assume worst case scenarios which would be > 200 app friends.

Comment: You use the paging next/prev cursors that you get in the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/me/friends?fields=picture&limit=100
```

This API call will get the profile pictures of 100 friends, and it´s only ONE API call. If there are more App friends, you can use paging to get the next 100 profile pictures. You don´t need to use a separate API call for each friend. It´s called "field expansion": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Comment: Ohhh, I thought it would count as 100 api calls. Thanks for the information! Exactly what I was looking for.